# Rubymine: How to run single test via Rail5 test runner?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubymine

You can run single test using Rails 5 test runner by specifying the file and the linenumber like the following:

```
rails test path/to/test:55
```

In RubyMine, you can run single test from context menu on a test you want to run. However, since it is not via the above test runner, it does not use a spring preloader and takes long to launch a test.

I have tried to create new Run/Debug configuration to run test via spring, but I am still not sure how to do it.

Please let me know how to run single test via Rail5 test runner?